# Is this Feynman diagram possible or not?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, feynman-diagrams

Is this possible or not, and how do you know?
I am taking the convention of time being from left to right.

[image]

Comment: Does this not violate lepton number conservation at each vertex?

Comment: Could you please explain how :)?

Comment: Those should be antineutrinos not neutrinos.  Otherwise it's OK. See https://cds.cern.ch/record/248487/files/ppe-93-065.pdf for details

Comment: @RogerJBarlow Hi, thanks for replying. How come it would be allowed with antineutrinos and no neutrinos? I am clearly missing some fundamental understanding !

Comment: As @Charlie says, it's due to conservation of lepton number. You can/should google that.

Comment: @RogerJBarlow. I have, and from my understanding, the lepton number is +2 before and after, and thus at each vertex?   I can feel I am really missing the forest for the trees here!!!

Comment: But it's zero for the intermediate W state

Comment: the point of using arrows is that they don't reverse along a Fermionic line

Comment: @DanielJRadford Lepton number has to be conserved *at each vertex*. The $W^-$ boson has lepton number of $0$, the electron + electron neutrino have a total lepton number of $2$, so $2$ lepton number is vanishing at the first vertex and appearing at the second.

Comment: @Charlie Thank you for taking the time to explain that to me! Have been searching all night online and books for a concrete answer! That was my inclining but needed solid confirmation!

Comment: @RogerJBarlow Thankyou !

Answer (score 1):

As drawn, your diagram shows a matter neutrino and a matter electron combining to form a virtual $W$ boson, which then relaxes back into a matter neutrino and a matter electron.  That is *not* allowed, because the initial and final states have lepton number $+2$, while the intermediate state has lepton number $0$.  In the Standard Model, lepton number is a conserved quantity at every vertex.

However, if you reverse the direction of the arrows on the neutrino lines, your diagram would then show the [s-channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelstam_variables) charged-current scattering between antineutrinos and electrons. The differences between charged-current and neutral-current scattering were important at [SNO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudbury_Neutrino_Observatory) in unraveling the "solar neutrino problem."